# Cloudflare Load Balancer 405 Error on Post Request

Tags: authentication, nginx, proxy, load-balancing, http-status-code-405

I am currently having issues making POST requests to a load-balanced backend. (The load balancer is managed by Cloudflare).

Making POST requests directly to the individual servers does not cause any trouble. Neither does making GET requests (even through the load balancer).

However, when I make a POST request through the load balancer's URL it returns with a 405 error.

The logic I am attempting to create follows this:
`request (with basic authentication)` →
`Cloudflare load balancer` →
`server` →
`server's localhost:<special port>`

This is not my area of expertise, but I have a suspicion it has to do with my Nginx config.
Each server is configured with a proxy_pass to redirect to a specific localhost port.

Here is my `<website>.com.conf`:

```
server {
        server_name <site>;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:<port>;

                proxy_set_header Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $proxy_protocol_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
        }

        # ...Certbot security settings...

}
server {
    if ($host = <site>) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name <site>;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Here is the format of the type of requests I might be making:

```
curl --location --request POST '<Load balancer URL>' \
--header 'Authorization: <Basic Auth for Backend>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '
<JSON formatted request>
'
```

Using the '-v' flag returns this:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying <IP>:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <Load Balancer URL> (<IP>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=<Country>; ST=<State>; L=<City>; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN= <...>
*  start date: May 27 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: May 27 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "<Load Balancer URL>" matched cert's "*.<...>"
*  issuer: C=<Country>; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=Cloudflare Inc <...>
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55f8f7998820)
> POST / HTTP/2
> Host: <Load Balancer URL>
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> authorization: <Backend Authentication>
> content-type: application/json
> content-length: 27
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 256)!
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2 405 
< date: Thu, 11 Mar 2021 13:58:46 GMT
< content-type: text/html
< set-cookie: __cfduid=d89c9a3af7f0a5bf4a217c57c9b2458711615471126; expires=Sat, 10-Apr-21 13:58:46 GMT; path=/; domain=<...>; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
< cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
< cf-request-id: 08c32e3ef70000f03155b09000000001
< expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< set-cookie: __cflb=04dToTKvCmh27ted7uGQoG5sVWTpTxCb8xpz4UsNcD; SameSite=None; Secure; path=/; expires=Thu, 11-Mar-21 14:28:46 GMT; HttpOnly
< strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< server: cloudflare
< cf-ray: 62e54cab2d88f031-EWR
< 
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host rpc-testnet.diviproject.org left intact
```

This is my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        }

http {

                        
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        
        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

                        
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;         ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

                        
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

                        
        gzip on;

                                                
                        
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

And there are no syntactical errors:

`nginx -t`

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I know I might be missing something obvious, but despite my research, I could not find anything on this subject. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you do a curl request with `-v` flag added for the post and add all the logs to your question

Comment: Yes I can, I have edited my question.

Comment: Can you check if request has reached your application or not? Also what it shows in its own log?

Comment: I am fairly certain that it hasn't reached the application, but that is a good idea to check anyway.

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't get through to the backend application, however `/var/log/nginx/access.log` logs this when I try to connect through the load balancer: `<IP> - <basic authentication username> [11/Mar/2021:14:37:18 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 166 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.26.10"` (I am using postman to test some of my requests).

Comment: Can you at the whole nginx file ? preferably output of `nginx -T`

Comment: Yes.
Okay, I have added the uncommented parts of my nginx.conf file, as well as the output of nginx -t to my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229772/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-octal).